# Python replacing characters in a dictionary of strings using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries: `clues` where the key is a letter and the value is its corresponding symbol, and `words` where the key is a word made up of entirely symbols, and the value is the word with all of the symbols replaced by the correct letters.

For example, clues may look like this:

```
clues = {'!':'A', '2':'B', '^':'C'}
```

And words like this:

```
words = {'!2^':'ABC', '^12':'CAB'}
```

I need to loop through each character of each key in `words` and replace any character that corresponds to any key in the `clues` dictionary.

Comment: What will `words` look like when you're done?

Comment: Letting you know that you haven't been clear with the expected output part.

Comment: That `clues` dictionary is the opposite of being helpful. It would be more useful if the symbol was the key, and the decrypted letter was the value.

Comment: Any chance you could invert the role of keys and values in the clues dict? Otherwise lookups might be quite expensive.

Comment: That can easily be done, thanks. Ill make a change to the original post now :)

Comment: `words` already contains the translated strings. What do you need your program to do?

Comment: why not just store the chars separately?

Comment: @interjay It is not obvious on a quick reading (at least wasn't for me), but the last entry does not contains the translated string as value: as I understood it, `{ '^12':'CAB'}` should map to `{ 'C1B':'CAB'}`

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Maybe, or maybe it's a typo between `1` and `!`. I'm voting to close because OP refuses to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

clues = {'!':'A', '2':'B', '^':'C'}

d = ['!2^', '^!2']

words = {}

for i in d:
    words[i]=''
    for x in i:
        words[i] += clues[x]

print words
```

Don't forget to confirm it as an answer if it helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
clues = {'!':'A', '2':'B', '^':'C'}
words = {'!2^':'ABC', '^12':'CAB'}

result = { "".join([clues.get(c,c) for c in k]):v for k,v in words.items() }

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Producing:

```
{'ABC': 'ABC', 'C1B': 'CAB'}
```